# C# SQL Update my Scores

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL database and would like to have the data in the database updated while my **C#** program is running. Unfortunately, so far I have not find solution.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=P*****;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=True"))
            {   //open connection
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Daten SET Siege = @Siege, Niederlagen = @Niederlagen Where username = @username"))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Siege", richtigerTipp);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Niederlagen", falscherTipp);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    connection.Open();

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    connection.Close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: *Unfortunately, so far I do not come to a solution*, what errors/issues are you facing?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: you never set a "link" between connection and command.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `connection` on the `command`. Use an overload of the constructor of the command and pass a second argument as a connection.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Daten SET Siege = @Siege, Niederlagen = @Niederlagen Where username = @username", 
                                            connection))
{
   ...
}
```

Or, you could define it on the `Connection` property inside the `using` command scope:

```
command.Connection = connection;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must associate your connection with your command As:

```
command.Connection = connection
```